# windows 8 modern ui apps - access to data

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

Where can i find folder with installed modern ui apps? Im developing some app which uses .txt files to store information (win8 doesnot support datebase on arm - facepalm) but they seem to not work properly - thats why i want to access them.
Thanks!

Comment: SQLite is supported on ARM see http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/08/07/updated-how-to-using-sqlite-from-windows-store-apps.aspx

Comment: I have installed it and then VS told me that sqlLIte is not supporting "any CPU" settings.

Comment: I have not worked with it, but Tim's post that I referenced in the previous comment seems to address that specifically - in that you did have to target each environment specifically x64, x86, ARM but their newer installer simplifies this for you.

Answer (score 2):

That is not the correct way of doing things in Metro.  I assume you mean db files, or txt files.  Simply access the local text file from the project folder.

Here is a great tutorial on how you would go about doing so: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/432876/Windows-8-The-Right-Way-to-Read-Write-Files-in-Win

An example:

```
    private async void ProjectFile()
{
    // settings
    var _Path = @"Metro.Helpers.Tests\MyFolder\MyFolder.txt";
    var _Folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;

    // acquire file
    var _File = await _Folder.GetFileAsync(_Path);
    Assert.IsNotNull(_File, "Acquire file");

    // read content
    var _ReadThis = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(_File);
    Assert.AreEqual("Hello world!", _ReadThis, "Contents correct");
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you are right... When I try to save something in "installed location" i receive exception "acces denied". Maybe it is not possible to write into project files? I will try using local/roaming storage once again (using another code)

Comment: You do not write in Project Files, you use Local and Roaming data.

You only read from Project Files.